# How to subtract days from a date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to know how I can subtract days from a date, in my example I've this variable:

```
var tot = 2;
```

And this is my date actually returned from `moment.js`

> Mon Oct 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)

There is a way to subtract the day, in this case (2) provided by variable `tot`?

I'm waiting this result:

> Sat Oct 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Refer http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: @DilDilshan the question is about **JavaScript**.

Comment: Have you [checked the Moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)?  Really, it would have taken you far less time than to type in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`subtract` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) to subtract two days from the existing moment object. Note that this manipulates the original object instead of just returning the modified object:

```
var x = moment('2015-10-26 00:00:00')
console.log(x.toLocaleString()); // "Mon Oct 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100"

// subtract 2 days
x.subtract(2, 'days');

console.log(x.toLocaleString()); // "Sat Oct 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200"
```

Demo in the snippet below.

```js
var x = moment('2015-10-26 00:00:00')
console.log(x.toLocaleString());
x.subtract(2, 'days');
console.log(x.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="//gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```